# Customize order confirmation email in SagePay

Tags: opayo

We need to customize SagePay order confirmation mail.

We assigned  `'eMailMessage'=><p>test</p>`

```
Your order from abc has been successful.

The unique reference for this transaction is: 917-260650635

Dear Vijay V,

Thank you for your order. Your payment has been processed successfully.

test


Please quote your order number 917-260650635 in all correspondence with either abc or Sage Pay.



Bullet Point    Order total:1,200.00 GBP
Card used:Sagepay Test Visa, United Kingdom - Visa - XXXX XXXX XXXX 5559 - Attempt:1
Bullet Point    You bought:917-260650635
Description Quantity    Item Value  Item Tax    Item Total  Line Total
abc12   1   1200.000000 0.000000    1200.000000 1200.00
```

How we can customize complete template?

Edit:

We want to customize entire layout with Logo and other deatils:

```
Dear Xxxx Xxxxxx,

Thank you for your order with DDDD .

Your payment has been processed successfully.

The unique reference for this payment is XXX-XXXXXXXXXX, please quote this in all correspondence with either ABC or Sage Pay.

Order Total:  £xxx.xx

Card Used : Name, Card Type , Last Four Digits XXXX

Your Order: Order Reference#
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. You can't - you're limited to inserting the contents of the emailMessage field. You'll need to implement some sort of customer notification yourself, if you want to change the email styling / contents.